# How to call a php file to process an uploaded file with on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm a javascript and php beginner and I've been trying to get a solution for 2 days now and it might be easy but I couldn't find any solutions.
So, i have my index.php with a file input and a button and I want that when the user clicks on the button it executes a js function that will call my excelparse.php file to process the uploaded file but I dont know how i can call the excelparse.php file on the function.
How do I call the excelparse.php file on my on.click function?

```
    //index.php
    <form>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="ficheiro">Select a file</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="ficheiro">
</div>
<button type="button" id="parse" class="btn btn-light">Parse</button>
</form>

    //js.js
    parse.on("click", function() {

    });

    //excelparse.php
    $path_parts = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = $path_parts['extension'];
    if ($extension == 'xls') {
        $extension = 'Xls';
    }
    elseif ($extension == 'xlsx') {
        $extension = 'Xlsx';
    }

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],('files/tmp'));

    $reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($extension);
    $spreadsheet = $reader->load("files/tmp");
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();        
    foreach ($sheet ->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        $cellIterator = $row ->getCellIterator();
        $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);
        $array = array();
        foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
            if (!is_null($cell)) {
                $value = $cell->getFormattedValue();
                $array[] = $value;                                        
            }                
        }
        print_r($array);
    }
```

Comment: is it ok if page reloads or you need ajax call?

Comment: `<form enctype="multipart/form-data">` if uploading file is must.

Comment: @Drakula I wanted to parse the excel file using my excelparse.php file and then and print an array on the index.php file with the values of the excel cells,so yeah, i would need ajax I guess

Answer (score 0):

You can not execute PHP commands in HTML file like Javascript.

PHP is a server side language, It will execute in server and push response to client.

Here you need to use `AJAX` to call a `URL (your php file)` in javascript (jQuery is easy).

[jQuery Ajax Request](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

A simple jQuery Ajax request be like,

```
    function callPhp() {

      $.ajax({
        url: "http://server.com/yourPhpFileUrl.php"
      }).done(function() {
         alert(0);
      });

   }
```

**In your code**

You can submit a file using form submit method,

```
<form action='http://server.com/yourPhpFileUrl.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data>
```

**Otherwise**

You can also send file using AJAX request

[File upload using Ajax](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/the-basics-of-file-upload-in-php/)

Comment: so, can I add your piece of code to my js.js file inside the parse.on(click) function?

Comment: My code will not do what you exactly want to do, But thats is a simple example. You can refer by clicking above link I mentioned in answer,
Good luck